# Error en el sistema de validación DJango

Tags: html, css

Veran, en un formulario he creado un sistema de validación:

```
class nue_categoria(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=categoria
        fields=('nombre','descripcion','foto')
    def clean_nombre(self):
        may=self.cleaned_data['nombre'][0]
        if may<'A' or may>'Z':
            raise forms.ValidationError("¡El nombre debe empezar en mayuscula!")
        return self.cleaned_data['nombre']
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data=self.cleaned_data
        return cleaned_data
```

Lo cual lleva a la siguiente vista:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El sistema comprueba que el atributo nombre empiece con una letra mayúscula, pero al probarlo, me pasa esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El mensaje de error se come parte de la pantalla y queda muy poco estetico.
Paso el código css:

```
body{
    background-color: #DDDDDD;
}

h1{
    background-color: #64BC31;
    color: white;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

div{
    text-align: center;
}

form{
    background-color: #C9FAB9;
}

.completito{
    width:400px;
    height:250px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #336699;
}
button{
    color: black;
    background: #77D757;
    font-weight: bolder;
}
```

Codigo HTML:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<html>
<head>
<title>Categoria Nueva</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster&subset=latin,latin-ext" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'estaticos/maquillar.css' %}">
</head>
<body class="container">
<h1>Nueva Categoria</h1>
<div id="formulario">
<form method="POST" class="completito" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <br><br>
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ forma.as_p }}
            <button type="submit">Insertar</button>
        </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Edito: He comprobado el codigo fuente de mi vista.
Aqui esta el codigo antes de provocar el error:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Categoria Nueva</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster&subset=latin,latin-ext" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/estaticos/maquillar.css">
</head>
<body class="container">
<h1>Nueva Categoria</h1>
<div id="formulario">
<form method="POST" class="completito" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <br><br>
            <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='kKhQDtM85Wak6eSmegcxaOQkwbAe0xXhRHoZZSs1ZRKkFiYlXPvVnEZ1GGjwgBk8' />
            <p><label for="id_nombre">Nombre:</label> <input id="id_nombre" maxlength="25" name="nombre" type="text" required /></p>
<p><label for="id_descripcion">Descripcion:</label> <input id="id_descripcion" maxlength="255" name="descripcion" type="text" required /></p>
<p><label for="id_foto">Foto:</label> <input id="id_foto" name="foto" type="file" required /></p>
            <button type="submit">Insertar</button>
        </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Y aqui el codigo tras provocar el error de validación:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Categoria Nueva</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster&subset=latin,latin-ext" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/estaticos/maquillar.css">
</head>
<body class="container">
<h1>Nueva Categoria</h1>
<div id="formulario">
<form method="POST" class="completito" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <br><br>
            <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='Yea7uxQWmsfDDlG7GZzpu1sio9zLlSa5vbhgQWwPgnPDcpM6pySNHRBZyEi3BWxW' />
            <ul class="errorlist"><li>¡El nombre debe empezar en mayuscula!</li></ul>
<p><label for="id_nombre">Nombre:</label> <input id="id_nombre" maxlength="25" name="nombre" type="text" value="hu" required /></p>
<p><label for="id_descripcion">Descripcion:</label> <input id="id_descripcion" maxlength="255" name="descripcion" type="text" value="ii" required /></p>
<p><label for="id_foto">Foto:</label> <input id="id_foto" name="foto" type="file" required /></p>
            <button type="submit">Insertar</button>
        </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No queda claro __qué es lo que pasa__. ¿Es un problema en la lógica de validación o en la presentación? ¿Cuál es el resultado esperado? Usa este enlace para __[edit]__ tu pregunta.

Comment: He editado mi pregunta para añadir más detalles.

Comment: Muestra tu template para ver donde pusiste `form.errors`

Comment: He editado añadiendo HTML. No hay ningun form.errors por ahora.

Comment: Yo creo que debes omitir de tu pregunta la parte de Django. Pero debes crear un __[mcve]__: provoca que aparezca el error y copia/pega el HTML __generado__, junto con los estilos correspondientes. Es eso lo que tienes corregir. Solo el mensaje de error, para que aparezca como tu quieras. Y solo tienes que hacerlo con estilos, por lo tanto, Django no forma parte de tu ecuación y solo te distrae de la solución.

Comment: @toledano Vale, he sustituido la etiqueta DJango por HTML y he editado para añadir el codigo fuente en la pagina.